# Container size equal to image height in RWD

Tags: css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Asatani/Lheu70jn/

I have recently decided to delve into the world of RWD and I am having trouble getting some things to work as expected. This particular issue is related to parallaxing a hero image at the top of my page. I understand how to make the image scale and it works exactly how I need it to, but the rest of the page will not shift up to fill the gap when I shrink the viewport. The hero image's position is relative with a width of 100vw and a height of 50vh. Immediately below that is a spacer div (with just a flat background color) to kind of frame the hero image. When viewed on my computer, it looks perfect. When viewed from my phone, the image is sized correctly, but the spacer is way down the page and will not adjust when the viewport adjusts.

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="topbar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Placeholder</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Placeholder</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Placeholder</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Placeholder</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="background1"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
        <article>
            <p><span class="auto-style1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.</span><br></p>
            <p><span class="auto-style2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.</span><br></p>
            <p><span class="auto-style3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.</span><br></p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <p><span class="auto-style4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.</span><br></p>
            <p><span class="auto-style5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.</span><br></p>
            <p><span class="auto-style6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.</span><br></p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <p><span class="auto-style7">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.</span><br></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.<br></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque 
            porttitor nisl lectus, ac posuere purus faucibus eu. Maecenas a 
            ultricies risus. Ut id vulputate leo, sed fermentum velit. Duis id 
            tortor ac felis tincidunt varius. Duis non nulla erat. Vestibulum 
            dapibus, libero sit amet porttitor aliquam, dolor orci mollis augue, 
            id euismod nunc ipsum vitae libero. Phasellus ultricies eros in 
            finibus lobortis. Nunc interdum elit in sagittis pulvinar. Aliquam a 
            libero sit amet nisl lobortis ullamcorper. Vivamus elementum urna a 
            ullamcorper accumsan.<br>
            Quisque neque arcu, gravida id luctus quis, tempor at quam. Etiam id 
            cursus risus. Mauris eu turpis in erat dignissim porta at ac tortor. 
            Curabitur quis auctor ipsum. Nulla neque diam, congue vel fringilla 
            at, vehicula vitae diam. Proin ut volutpat odio. Aliquam erat 
            volutpat.<br>
            Donec in tempor dui. Nullam iaculis tempus porttitor. Phasellus vel 
            lectus auctor, mollis elit vel, sagittis nibh. Etiam ut sem id erat 
            sodales placerat. Etiam viverra tellus at nunc aliquam, ullamcorper 
            malesuada felis pharetra. Morbi gravida enim ut lectus bibendum 
            molestie. Pellentesque eget quam vulputate nibh maximus 
            pellentesque. Curabitur sed bibendum neque, et gravida est. Sed 
            pellentesque est nec eros cursus mollis. Phasellus vitae diam a mi 
            viverra finibus a nec orci.<br>
            Quisque eu nisi vel urna finibus porta. Integer volutpat, enim non 
            hendrerit dignissim, ligula tortor maximus dolor, vel fermentum mi 
            metus nec enim. Nunc dictum sed urna sit amet luctus. Nulla suscipit 
            rhoncus erat, vel semper sem ultrices vitae. Nulla blandit odio at 
            justo interdum placerat. Maecenas eros tellus, molestie et metus 
            non, pulvinar bibendum elit. Donec dignissim est pharetra, auctor mi 
            ac, eleifend nulla. Nam non vestibulum nunc. Donec at massa metus. 
            Donec a facilisis nulla, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Maecenas velit 
            urna, hendrerit non orci in, euismod venenatis enim. Mauris 
            scelerisque venenatis nisl, ut lobortis nunc pretium sit amet. Sed 
            ac blandit nulla. Integer mattis rutrum mi et venenatis.<br>
            Donec id fermentum nisi. Quisque vitae libero vestibulum, rutrum 
            nibh nec, finibus diam. Cras malesuada rhoncus dui, in vulputate 
            tellus tristique in. Integer vestibulum porta porttitor. 
            Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada 
            fames ac turpis egestas. Donec placerat pulvinar cursus. Sed 
            ullamcorper sapien quis fringilla rutrum. Fusce et lacinia turpis, 
            vitae dapibus tellus. Quisque luctus ac erat vitae tempor.<br></p>
        </article>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
margin: 90px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;

}
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #fff;
color: #000;
}
#topbar {
top: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
background:url(../images/header_logo.png) left 25px top 10px no-repeat, url(../images/header_bg.png) center bottom repeat-x;
z-index: 50;
}
nav {

}
nav ul  {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 200px;
list-style:none;
}
nav ul li{
display:block;
float:left;
padding:3px 15px;
}
nav ul li a {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
transition: all .25s ease;
color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
color: #00f;
}
article {
background: #fff;
}
aside {
}
feed {
}
footer {
}
a {
color: #00f;
}
a:active {
}
.spacer {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
background-color: #1588cc;

}
.background1 {
background-image: url("https://bhope.caria.com/images/bridges_hero.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center -200px;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
height: 50vh;
clear: both;
z-index: -1;
}
.background2 {
background-image: url("1");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 97% top;
background-size: 10%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vw;
z-index: -1;
}
.background3 {
background-image: url("2");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 5% top;
background-size: 50%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vw;
z-index: -1;
}
    .auto-style1 {
        color: #FF0000;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        color: #00FF00;
    }
    .auto-style3 {
        color: #0000FF;
    }
    .auto-style4 {
        color: #FFFF00;
    }
    .auto-style5 {
        color: #FF00FF;
    }
    .auto-style6 {
        color: #00FFFF;
    }
    .auto-style7 {
        color: #008080;
    }
```

Comment: problem is with background-position negative pixels..

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.